# XCode Source Control over windows server

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4

How I can Install a versioning source control to windows serve and connect this control to XCode 4.x to make the ability for multi developer to work on the same project (Check in and out from XCode) and host this version on my own servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [version control system like GIT](http://msysgit.github.com/) on windows.

See this article : [version control system with xcode-4 and git](http://www.smartapps.co/2011/01/version-control-system-with-xcode-4-and-git/)

And then set the main repository to be the one on the windows server.

Comment: I'm trying to try this application but I'm confused, what is the configurations I must do it on windows side and how to generate a link to use it with XCode